# SSIS call to SMO works in Visual Studio but fails when run from a SQL Agent Job on the server. Jobs not using SMO work fine

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssis, smo

I wrote an SSIS 2017 package that uses SMO (sql server management ojects) to synch my disaster recovery (DR) server with my production server.  Both servers are 2017.  The package runs fine on the DR server from Visual Studio 2017 (SSDT) using my network login but fails when run from the DR server as a sql agent job with this error:

**Script Task:Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.**

I have tried running the sql agent job using a proxy with my network login and still receive the error.  Wrapping the code block in a Try/Catch didn't result in a better error message.  I was able to successfully connect using SMO from a powershell script in a sql agent job on the DR server.  Sample code:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null
$serverInstance = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') Server1
```

**Other Details about the script task:**

Target Server Version: SQL Server 2017

Target Framework: .Net Framework 4.5 *(The servers have 4.6.2)*

References:

- D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
  Server\140\DTS\Tasks\Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll
- D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
  Server\140\DTS\Tasks\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll

**Code:**

```
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo
Dim smoSourceServer As Server = New Server("Server1")
```

Any help or ideas on what to try to get this working are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I usually get this nasty generic error when I forgot to deploy a DLL to the GAC or when running in 64bit mode when a component of my package is only installed in 32bit.  Version differences on the DLLS can also cause this if I remember correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @JoeC !  I checked the GAC and can see the DLLS in the cache: Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies:

  Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL
  Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL

I tried running in 32 bit too and that didn't help.

Comment: @JoeC The versions I can see in the reference selection in SSDT are 14.100.0.0.  Could that be the issue?

Comment: I believe a similar issue happened to me in the past its worth trying.